# How to pipe a directory name into Remove-Item?

Tags: powershell, piping

I'm not very savvy with powershell, so any help is appreciated.

I have a drive that holds users profiles. I need to remove a specific file from each user's profile. It's structured something like this. (Names changed to protect the innocent.)

> - E:\Profiles
>
>   - UserID
>
>     - Documents
>     - OtherFolders
>     - DirectoryToDeleteFrom
>
>       - FileToDelete.txt
>   - UserID2
>
>     - ...
>     - ...

I could use the following command to delete all of the files I need to get to, but it's unbearably slow as it's recursing through all of the other folders under UserID.

```
#this one would work perfectly, but is terribly slow
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Profiles -Include FileToDelete.txt -Recurse
```

I know exactly where each file resides, so I thought that I could do this.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Profiles' -Exclude *.lnk)|ForEach-Object{Remove-item -path 'E:\Profiles\' + $_.Name + '\Path\To\File\FileToDelete.txt'}
```

But I get the following error message:

> Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '+'. At line:1 char:70
>   + (Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Profiles' -Exclude *.lnk)|ForEach-Object{Remove-item ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

I thought it was because I was passing `Remove-Item` a bad file path, but the following command generates the correct paths.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Profiles' -Exclude *.lnk)|ForEach-Object{'E:\Profiles\' + $_.Name + '\Path\To\File\FileToDelete.txt'}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you construct a string on the fly to be used inline, by another command, then put brackets around the path:

```powershell
..{Remove-item -path ('E:\Profiles\' + $_.Name + '\Path\To\File\FileToDelete.txt')}
```